# How can I substitute a look-up table for the Sin function?

Tags: c++, lookup, trigonometry

Okay, so the Sin function takes in a radius, and returns the sine of that radius.

I have heard that practically any function can be replaced with a look-up table.

Irregardless of how I use the sin function, how can I use my own look-up table in substitution of sin?

Lets make a simple example [found here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/)

```
/* sin example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* sin */

int main ()
{
  double param, result;
  param = 0.53;
  result = sin (param);
  printf ("The sine of %f is %f.\n", param, result );
  return 0;
}
```

Lets say I want to replace the sin function there with my own look-up table with 256 floating points.

```
#define TableSize 256.f

float SinArray[TableSize];
for(int i = 0; i < TableSize; i++) 
{
    // sin
    SinArray[i] = static_cast<float>(sin( (i/TableSize)*(2.f*m_pi) ));
}
```

How can I now use this table in substitution to using the sin function.

You might be asking "Why? Why not just use the sin function?" well it's because I'm using the sin function to waveshape audio input. If I can use a look-up table, I can create sawtooth or triangle shapes to

Since the sin function takes in a radius and returns the sine of that radius, how can I duplicate this action with a look-up table? How do I even go about doing this?

Comment: So.. what is the problem with what you are currently doing?

Comment: `#define TableSize 256.f ... SinArray[TableSize];` That's impossibly going to work! You certainly can't use `float` values to specify array dimensions!!

Comment: Not to mention `SinArray` is an array of...ummm...who knows.

Comment: I disagree that *"practically any function can be replaced with a look-up table"*. How are you going to replace `int foo(int bar){return bar + 1;}` with a look-up table, for example? There are infinitely many functions which would require an infinitely sized look-up table (my example is constrained by the range of int, but the principle holds).

Comment: Well, like I pointed out, I created a bunch of other tables like Sawtooth, Triangle, Square and this SinArray. It's just one of many. 

So when I use the sin() I already have a sine table I could use. Not only that, I can substitute other tables like Saw, triangle, etc. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HaroonPiracha Sounds you're trying to solve a XY problem! What's your actual intend to use a lookup table rather than (the most probably available) FPU operations?? What's your bottleneck, are you experiencing any performance drawbacks using the standard `sin()` function vs. using a lookup table? Are you going for premature optimization?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He goes over that toward the end of his question, doesn't he?

Comment: @tmyklebu _'He goes over that toward the end ...'_ At least not very clearly :P ...

Comment: No, No optimization, no performance drawbacks. My Sin function is usually used to waveshape audio input. 

In theory, I can use my own drawn waves in some table fitted with 256 points and interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpolate between two values in the table

pseudocode:

```
float sin(float radius) {
  radius = radius modulo 2*m_pi;
  int idx = floor(TableSize * radius/2*m_pi);
  float r = TableSize * radius/2*m_pi - idx;
  return SinArray[idx] * (1-r) + SinArray[idx+1] * r;
}
```

Comment: Wow this actually may do the job. 

SO you get the modulo of radius over 2*m_pi, then you use the (TableSize * radius/2*m_pi) to determine the position inside the table. 

I'm going to try to see if I could use a spline interpolation instead.

Comment: @HaroonPiracha actually it might be better to normalize radius to the 0..1 range. Then you can use `modf` function for modulo and other computations get easier too.

Answer (score 0):

Map radii at regular intervals to their sin values, that's your table. When you want to use it, round the radius you want a value for to the nearest key in your table, that's your sin value.

Or round the radius you want a value for to the nearest integer and index into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see why you'd do this on a normal / modern machine - `sin()` is a hardware instruction.

But, for fun, you can do something like this:

```
const double tau = 2 * M_PI;

class Sin
{
public:
    Sin(int tableSize = 256)
        : tableSize_(tableSize)
    {
        initSinTable();
    }
    double operator()(double radians) const
    {
        double mapped = mapDomain(radians);
        int idx = (int)floor(tableSize_ * mapped / tau);
        double lambda = tableSize_ * mapped / tau - idx;
        double lower = sinArray[idx] ;
        double upper = 0;
        if (idx < tableSize_ - 1)
            upper = sinArray[idx + 1];
        double res = lower * (1 - lambda) + upper *lambda;
        return res;
    }
private:
    static double mapDomain(double d) 
    {

        double mapped = fmod(d, tau);
        if (mapped < 0)
            mapped += tau;
        return mapped;

    }
    int tableSize_;
    std::vector<double> sinArray;
    void initSinTable()
    {

        sinArray.resize(tableSize_);
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize_; ++i)
        {
            sinArray[i] = sin((i*1.0 / tableSize_)*tau);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Sin mySin(512); 
    std::cout << mySin(tau / 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sin(tau / 6) << std::endl;
}
```

As for the use of `tau`, see: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_%282%CF%80%29#tau)

Comment: `sin`'s still not very fast, though.  Crappy approximations still win.

Comment: Well, I make no claim that the above is faster for `sin`. But certainly the technique can be very useful if you need many evaluations of a more complex function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation, generalised to be reusable for arbitrary functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cmath>

#define LOG(X) (std::cout << X << '\n')

template <typename Num>
class Lookup
{
  public:
    Lookup(Num (*func)(Num), Num from, Num to, size_t num_samples)
      : from_(from), to_(to), x_(double(num_samples - 1) / (to - from))
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i)
        {
            Num num = (to - from) * i / (num_samples - 1);
            Num sample = func(num);
            LOG("[" << i << "] f(" << num << ") == " << sample);
            samples_.push_back(sample);
        }
    }

    Num operator()(Num n) const
    {
        size_t index = round((n - from_) * x_);
        LOG("(" << n << ") ~@ [" << (n - from_) << " / " << (to_ - from_)
            << " * " << (samples_.size() - 1) << "] == [" << index << "] == "
            << samples_.at(index) << "]");
        return samples_.at(index);
    }

  private:
    static Num round(Num n) { return std::floor(n + 0.5); }

    std::vector<Num> samples_;
    Num from_, to_, x_;
};

int main()
{
    Lookup<double> lsin(std::sin, 0.0, 1.0, 21);

    for (double d = 0; d <= 1.0; d += 0.1)
        std::cout << d << ' ' << sin(d) << ' ' << lsin(d) << '\n';
}
```

It's intended for `float` or `double` types - probably wouldn't work with anything else given the use of `floor` and divisions where premature truncation to integers would be problematic.

The "mysteriously" named `x_` is precalculated to speed up `operator()(Num)`; it could have been calculated as an amount to divide by, but multiplication is sometimes faster in terms of clock cycles.

Logging just shows it's working as intended:

```
[0] f(0) == 0
[1] f(0.05) == 0.0499792
[2] f(0.1) == 0.0998334
[3] f(0.15) == 0.149438
[4] f(0.2) == 0.198669
[5] f(0.25) == 0.247404
[6] f(0.3) == 0.29552
[7] f(0.35) == 0.342898
[8] f(0.4) == 0.389418
[9] f(0.45) == 0.434966
[10] f(0.5) == 0.479426
[11] f(0.55) == 0.522687
[12] f(0.6) == 0.564642
[13] f(0.65) == 0.605186
[14] f(0.7) == 0.644218
[15] f(0.75) == 0.681639
[16] f(0.8) == 0.717356
[17] f(0.85) == 0.75128
[18] f(0.9) == 0.783327
[19] f(0.95) == 0.813416
[20] f(1) == 0.841471
(0) ~@ [0 / 1 * 20] == [0] == 0]
0 0 0
(0.1) ~@ [0.1 / 1 * 20] == [2] == 0.0998334]
0.1 0.0998334 0.0998334
(0.2) ~@ [0.2 / 1 * 20] == [4] == 0.198669]
0.2 0.198669 0.198669
(0.3) ~@ [0.3 / 1 * 20] == [6] == 0.29552]
0.3 0.29552 0.29552
(0.4) ~@ [0.4 / 1 * 20] == [8] == 0.389418]
0.4 0.389418 0.389418
(0.5) ~@ [0.5 / 1 * 20] == [10] == 0.479426]
0.5 0.479426 0.479426
(0.6) ~@ [0.6 / 1 * 20] == [12] == 0.564642]
0.6 0.564642 0.564642
(0.7) ~@ [0.7 / 1 * 20] == [14] == 0.644218]
0.7 0.644218 0.644218
(0.8) ~@ [0.8 / 1 * 20] == [16] == 0.717356]
0.8 0.717356 0.717356
(0.9) ~@ [0.9 / 1 * 20] == [18] == 0.783327]
0.9 0.783327 0.783327
(1) ~@ [1 / 1 * 20] == [20] == 0.841471]
1 0.841471 0.841471
```